# Change parent (div) height to the size of its child (p) after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

    var totalHeight = 0

    var $p = $("#cwt-help").children();

    $p.each(function () {
        totalHeight += $("#cwt-help").outerHeight();
    });

    $("#cwt-help").css({ "height": totalHeight })
});
```

I am trying to resize parent div to match the height of its child after windows resize. The problem I have is with this code that I get the height before the resize. How can I get the resulting height? Thanks!

Comment: The natural behavior of a `div` is to expand to enclose its content, if it hasn't explicitly been given a size ... so, can you just leave the size off to begin with?  Alternatively, you could give it a `min-height` and `min-width` to define the smallest it should be, then just let it grow as it needs to.  The best solution depends a lot on the actual situation, which you don't describe in your question.

Comment: Why it can't be resolved using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The code is executed when the `resize` event occurs...
And you want it to be executed after the event.

So what about a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) ?

I suppose that 100 milliseconds after the event is enought.

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

  setTimeout(function(){
    var totalHeight = 0

    var $p = $("#cwt-help").children();

    $p.each(function () {
        totalHeight += $("#cwt-help").outerHeight();
    });

    $("#cwt-help").css({ "height": totalHeight });
  },100);
});
```

Comment: Actually the problem was in the 'outerHeight()' function. I am not sure why I used it but if I simply use height() it works. Problem solved. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, much easier. When resizing the window, you set the height to the `scrollHeight` of the element.

```js
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $("#cwt-help").css({ "height": $('#cwt-help').srollHeight });
});
```

```css
#cwt-help{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cwt-help">
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
  
  <p>Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```